# Check if line is empty in text file

Tags: php

I'm parsing a text file, and need to ignore blank / empty lines.

Text file:

```
00, Item one
01, Item two
02, Item three

03, Item four
04, Item five

05, Item six
```

PHP

```
// get the file contents
$file_contents = fopen($file["tmp_name"], "r");

// declare array to hold each line in file
$organizations = array();

// for each line in file
while (!feof($file_contents)) {
    // get current line in file
    $line = fgets($file_contents);

    // if line is empty or blank, skip
    if ($line[0] == "\n") {
        // push line to array
        // this is not being executed for blank / empty lines
        $organizations[] = "empty line...";
    }
    else {
        $organizations[] = $line;
    }
}
```

The above code is not working on empty lines. Empty / blank lines are still being pushed to the array, instead of the "empty line..." string.

How can I check to see if lines are blank / empty?

Comment: Have you tried php_eol? https://www.google.se/search?q=php_eol&oq=php_eol&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6722j0j4&client=ms-android-hms-tmobile-us&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful in displaying the char count in each line. I have it working now!

Answer (score 0):

```php
// get the file contents

$file_contents = fopen($file["tmp_name"], "r");

// declare array to hold each line in file

$organizations = array();

// for each line in file
while (!feof($file_contents)) {
  // get current line in file
  $line = fgets($file_contents);
  
  // by this method you can detect if line is empty or blank, skip
  if (sizeof(str_split($line)) < 3) {
    // push line to array
    // this is not being executed for blank / empty lines
    $organizations[] = "empty line...";
  }
  else {
    $organizations[] = $line;
  }
}
```